# LilyPond : how to write numbers before staves?

Tags: lilypond

I'm writing some exercises, one per line, and I would like to write a number before each one.

I can't figure out how to do that, so a little help would be appreciated!

My code is pretty simple :

```
\language "english"
\header {title = "C Major"}

{
  \time 4/4
c' d' e' f' d' e' f' g' e' f' g' a' f' g' a' b' g' a' b' c'' a' b' c'' d'' b' c'' d'' e'' c'' d'' e'' f'' 
}

{
  \time 4/4
f'' e'' d'' c'' e'' d'' c'' b' d'' c'' b' a' c'' b' a' g' b' a' g' f' a' g' f' e' g' f' e' d' f' e' d' c' 
}
```

Comment: *\markup* allows arbitrary text (above or below) which should work fine. But I would definitely add note lengths and bars, and I can't imagine, that your apostrophes are as intended (at least if relative notation is used, which simplifies the source somewhat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to number the staves automatically, you can write some Scheme and label each staff with `instrumentName = #(score-number)`:

```
\version "2.19.81"

#(define sn 0)

#(define (score-number)
   (set! sn (1+ sn))
   (string-append (number->string sn)))  % "."

\new Staff \with { instrumentName = #(score-number) } { \time 4/4 c' d' e' }

\new Staff \with { instrumentName = #(score-number) } { \time 4/4 c' d' e' }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Richard and Paco Vila for your  answers, that's perfect. Could you tell me where in the docs you finded those informations ?

Comment: instrumentName is documented here: http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/notation/writing-parts#instrument-names

the set command is in http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/notation/the-set-command

Answer (score 4):

The standard way of putting anything before a staff is by setting its instrumentName property.

You can put

```
\set Staff.instrumentName = "1"
```

into the music, or declare the staff adding a 'with' clause:

```
\new Staff \with { instrumentName = "1" } { \time 4/4 c' d' e' }

\new Staff \with { instrumentName = "2" } { \time 4/4 f'' e'' d'' }
```

[image: example rendering of the above lilypond code]